# I am unable to iterate nested objects on the basis of key in angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am working on Angular app and I have an [end point](https://api.mocki.io/v1/1db49fc3/courses-data) which return the following JSON as a response:

```json
{
    "SuggestedCourses": 
    [
        {"courseId": "1","courseName": "SCourese1"},
        {"courseId": "2","courseName": "SCourese2"}
    ],
    "AvailableCourses": 
    [
        {"courseId": "3","courseName": "SCourese1"},
        {"courseId": "4","courseName": "SCourese2"}
    ],
    "RegisteredCourses": 
    [
        {"courseId": "5","courseName": "SCourese1"},
        {"courseId": "6","courseName": "SCourese2"}
    ]
}
```

I want to iterate just `SuggestedCourses` and I tried following way:

**courses.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesService} from 'src/app/shared/services/courses.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _courseService:CoursesService) { }
  
coursesData=[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
this._courseService.getCourseData().subscribe(data=>this.coursesData=data)

  }
}
}
```

*`observeables` and `services` working correctly and getting the data successfully. but I can't display on HTML page as follow:*

**courses.component.html**

```html
<ul>               
    <li *ngFor="let s of coursesData.SuggestedCourses">
        <div>{{s.courseName}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BaseModuleModule} from './shared/base-module/base-module.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { QuizComponent } from './components/quiz/quiz.component'
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import {UserService} from './shared/services/user.service';
import { CoursesComponent } from './components/courses/courses.component';
import { CourseModuleComponent } from './components/course-module/course-module.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    QuizComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CourseModuleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BaseModuleModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when I run the code then it displays the following Error:

> The class 'CoursesComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

But when I iterate over any simple `JSON` (not nested) then it working correctly. Please let me know how I can solve this?

Also, let me know am I using the correct approach to do this task? if not, then please guide me that how I can do this task in another way?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you add the component code?

Comment: thanks @ApoorvaChikara ,i added the component code in question,please review it.

Comment: Yes, Also add your app.module code as the above code seems fine.

Comment: i also added app.module.ts code,Thanks

Comment: Can you do one thing, just don't take data from API try to save same data in coursesData in your component and then run the app. Does it still show the error? Your code seems fine in all the components.

Comment: when I put response data in the component, then it works fine, but why display error on API case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229296/discussion-between-ubaid-and-apoorva-chikara).

Comment: it sounds like there is something wrong with your CoursesComponent, which has nothing to do with your ngFor loop. to isolate the problem trying declaring your data locally, see if everything works, and then go from there.

Comment: thanks @Rick ,i tried this and working fine in the case if I save data locally

Comment: @Rick Yes we did that session already and now the error is related to JIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your **courses.component.ts**. From what I see, your endpoint is returning a JSON object, not an array.

So you have to change the `coursesData` type from **array** to **any** (or to create an interface with the properties).

I have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqujtr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with this.

Comment: thank you so much it is working fine,it was the solution ,but why it display the error in console "Cannot read property 'SuggestedCourses' of undefined", please can you [see it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqujtr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) how we can fix it

Comment: Oh, yes. The error is displayed, because for the first time, `coursesData` object is undefined (until you get the response from the server). To fix this, you can add an `*ngIf="coursesData"` on the `ul` element, or **?** in `*ngFor`, like this `coursesData?.SuggestedCourses`. I recommend you to use the `*ngIf` on `ul`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working perfectly.